# Javascript substitution of object's method

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I have a problems with object's manipulation in javascript

My code:

```
SearchField = function(){
this.Init = function()
{
    this.input = this.view.getElementsByTagName("input");
    this.input[0].onkeyup = this.UpdateEvent2;
    self = this;                        
}

this.UpdateEvent = function(){
    this.OnUpdate();
}

this.UpdateEvent2 = this.UpdateEvent.bind(this);

this.OnUpdate = function(){
    alert("Hello world from direct object");
};
```

}

Some explanations for this code: I used a bind method to pass as argument the Object itself, instead of event object.
So, I have a function OnUpdate with some code inside.

After Instantiation of my Object in some other part of my code I have some other lines:

```
...
targetController.prototype[targetMethodName] = function(targetController){
alert("core");
return selfController[selfMethodName](targetController);
}
...
```

Where targetController is a reference to my object and targetMethodeName is a method OnUpdate(). Then I try to assign a new function to this method, in other words, try to Substitute the original method OnUpdate with another method from another object. (It dosen't metter 'couse it dosen't work in anyway, even invoking alert("core").)

So, when I try to call this method like this: MyObject.OnUpdate() - result is an alert window with "Hello world from direct object".

The first quastion is how can I substitute this method by another one?

But, there's some interesting behavior if I assign this method directly to the event handler like this:

```
SearchField = function(){
this.Init = function()
{
    this.input = this.view.getElementsByTagName("input");
    this.input[0].onkeyup = this.OnUpdate;
    self = this;                        
}


this.OnUpdate = function(){
    alert("Hello world from direct object");
};
```

}

In this case everything works perfectly, so I have an alert window with "core" inside and another method from another object invoked with right arguments...

So, the second quastion is ... what's wrong in the first variant??? I don't want to assign my method directly to the event handler! I whant to call this method in any part of my code! How to do this?

P.S. As you can see I tried to do this with self instead of this and so on... Nothing helps!

Comment: One thing I don't understand is you put the new method on targetController.prototype rather than the instance itself.

Comment: Grape_mao, before those lines The object has already created but doesn't initialized by Init() method, so I put the new method to concrete object's instance rather than to a class object or targetController.prototype. But the event handler setup after that! By calling Init() method. This is doing 'course if I call Init before, it will always point to initial function, even I do this substitution in the second variant!

Comment: I still don't get it...is this what you want to do ? http://jsfiddle.net/m5XYe/

Comment: If there's still a problem, jsfiddle that reproduces it would help greatly.

Comment: I didn't see any results, but something like this with some changes: the event occurs not when Init() called, but when key pressed... Init just setup the callback.

Comment: Sorry, guys! I used ipad without console. Yes, that is what I want, but in my code it doesn't work! Will search... maybe I forgot something important... May be it should be reproduced with event handler as in original code...

Comment: Still work with events... http://jsfiddle.net/m5XYe/9/

Comment: There's another interesting behavior in original code: when I try to call this method directly right after I put another one, it works, but from the event it doesn't...

Comment: By the way, thank you guys! Dialog is important for me)) Still work alone... At this point I supposed something goes wrong in my spaghetti...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to overwrite a keyup function after the class is created?

One way you could do this is to init with the original function, then overwrite it:

```
<div id="field">
    <input type="text" value="search1" />
</div>

<div id="field2">
    <input type="text" value="search2" />
</div>

<script>
var SearchField = function (id) {
    this.init = function () {
        var me = this;
        this.el = document.getElementById(id);
        this.input = this.el.getElementsByTagName('input');
        this.input[0].addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            me.onKeyUp(e);
        });
        self = this;
    }
    this.onKeyUp = function (e) {
        console.log('onKeyUp');
    };
    this.init();
};

var search1 = new SearchField('field');

var search2 = new SearchField('field2');

// overwrite the key up function
search2.onKeyUp = function(e) {
    console.log('onKeyUp2');
};
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/CHK96/